# NSUserDefault update best practices

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am on Xcode 9.2, Objective-c.

I have registered my defaults with registerDefaults like Apple recommends. Everything works just fine.

Think of this simple scenario: i have one key/value pair in my defaults where the value is an NSMutableDictionary.

Now i'd like to add some key/value pairs to that specific dictionary in an app update. Cause the key already exists in my defaults, the value (dictionary) wont be overwritten with the new one in the registerDefaults method.

Of course i can read the dictionary from the defaults, add my new pairs and write them back. But i was wondering if there's a more elegant way or a best practice for updates?

Answer (score 0):

You should only register defaults once, when your app launches. Everything else should be manipulations of `UserDefaults`. So accessing the array, appending a value, and setting it back into the defaults is fine.

Comment: yes i register them once in app delegates appDidFinishLaunching method. i thought of a new app version/update where i need to extend already existing values. Injecting by read/write back is always an option, just was wondering if theres a better way for updates

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use silent push notification for old data update.

Note:

They can be used to inform the application of new content without having the user informed. Instead of displaying a notification alert, the application will be awakened in background and application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: will be called. You then have the opportunity to process any information transparently for the user :

Download some content
Synchronize some elements,
Inform the user directly within the application when he opens it back
Note that your time is limited to 30s.

To configure silent notifications

> To support silent remote notifications, add the remote-notification
>   value to the UIBackgroundModes array in your Info.plist file. To learn
>   more about this array, see UIBackgroundModes.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

> Configuring a Silent Notification
>
> The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property.
>   The content- available property with a value of 1 lets the remote
>   notification act as a silent notification. When a silent notification
>   arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get
>   new data from your server or do background information processing.
>   Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results
>   from a silent notification, but they can find out about it the next
>   time they open your app.
>
> For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert,
>   sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. If you don’t follow
>   this guidance, the incorrectly-configured notification might be
>   throttled and not delivered to the app in the background, and instead
>   of being silent is displayed to the user

Hope this help you. If you need any help you can ask.